# Stripe Subscriptions with email Invoices

Tags: python, stripe-payments

I'm trying to create an app where clients can choose the price for the product and subscribe to it.
However creating subscription from code:
`stripe.Subscription.create(customer=customer_id, items=[{'price': price_id}])`
gives me `This customer has no attached payment source or default payment method.` error. My question is, can I somehow create a subscription and send the payment to email for customers to pay manually? Perfectly, that payment method would be saved for the subscription to renew automatically.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to pass the [`payment_behavior` parameter](https://stripe.com/docs/api/subscriptions/create#create_subscription-payment_behavior) if you're attempting to create a Subscription without aa payment method (as is the case here).

If you would prefer an invoice to be e-mailed to the customer for payment, then pass the [`collection_method` parameter](https://stripe.com/docs/api/subscriptions/create#create_subscription-collection_method).

```
stripe.Subscription.create(
  payment_behavior='default_incomplete',
  collection_method='send_invoice',
  customer=customer_id,
  items=[{'price': price_id}]
)
```

Comment: Subscription is created, so big thanks, however I don't have any Invoice on my email. Any suggestions what may I do wrong?

Comment: Stripe doesn't send emails in test mode unfortunately.